# SQL Server 2014 login failed

Tags: remote-server, sql-server-2014-express

I have a remote connection problem. I can connect to SQL Server with Management Studio on my server. But when I try to connect remotely, it fails. The error is

> incorrect username or password

I'm sure that's true.

Comment: Check for remote connections options under ServerProperties\Connections